# Keep constant order of tabs on DXTabControl

Tags: wpf

Is there a property that prevents the DXtabControl from changing the tab items location when a tabItem in selected?

Right now whenever I select a tabItem it is moved to the bottom of the "stack".
I find it confusing.

My tab control has more than one row of tab items.

TX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXTabControl has a `FixedHeaders` attribute you can set.

You can give this a try:

```
<dx:DXTabControl>
  <dx:DXTabControl.View>
    <dx:TabControlMultiLineView FixedHeaders="True"/>
  </dx:DXTabControl.View>
</dx:DXTabControl>
```